# Real time face detection in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, tracking, face-detection, viola-jones, matlab-cvst

I'm trying to make a real time face detector using MATLAB. I found a sample code on the Mathworks' page, but it uses a sample video. What I'm having a problem with it that this code only can track the one it chooses to even with a few faces in the opening frame. I need it to track several faces at once. Is that possible with a change in this code that is not drastic. 
I found the following code on MathWorks' web page:

```
% Create a cascade detector object.
faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector();

% Read a video frame and run the detector.
videoFileReader = vision.VideoFileReader('visionface.avi');
videoFrame      = step(videoFileReader);
bbox            = step(faceDetector, videoFrame);

% Draw the returned bounding box around the detected face.
videoOut = insertObjectAnnotation(videoFrame,'rectangle',bbox,'Face');
figure, imshow(videoOut), title('Detected face');

% Get the skin tone information by extracting the Hue from the video frame
% converted to the HSV color space.
[hueChannel,~,~] = rgb2hsv(videoFrame);

% Display the Hue Channel data and draw the bounding box around the face.
figure, imshow(hueChannel), title('Hue channel data');
rectangle('Position',bbox(1,:),'LineWidth',2,'EdgeColor',[1 1 0])

% Detect the nose within the face region. The nose provides a more accurate
% measure of the skin tone because it does not contain any background
% pixels.
noseDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Nose');
faceImage    = imcrop(videoFrame,bbox(1,:));
noseBBox     = step(noseDetector,faceImage);

% The nose bounding box is defined relative to the cropped face image.
% Adjust the nose bounding box so that it is relative to the original video
% frame.
noseBBox(1,1:2) = noseBBox(1,1:2) + bbox(1,1:2);

% Create a tracker object.
tracker = vision.HistogramBasedTracker;

% Initialize the tracker histogram using the Hue channel pixels from the
% nose.
initializeObject(tracker, hueChannel, noseBBox(1,:));

% Create a video player object for displaying video frames.
videoInfo    = info(videoFileReader);
videoPlayer  = vision.VideoPlayer('Position',[300 300 videoInfo.VideoSize+30]);

% Track the face over successive video frames until the video is finished.
while ~isDone(videoFileReader)

% Extract the next video frame
videoFrame = step(videoFileReader);

% RGB -> HSV
[hueChannel,~,~] = rgb2hsv(videoFrame);

% Track using the Hue channel data
bbox = step(tracker, hueChannel);

% Insert a bounding box around the object being tracked
videoOut = insertObjectAnnotation(videoFrame,'rectangle',bbox,'Face');

% Display the annotated video frame using the video player object
step(videoPlayer, videoOut);

end

% Release resources
release(videoFileReader);
release(videoPlayer);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That example is designed to only track a single face.  For tracking multiple objects please take a look at this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html), that uses `vision.KalmanFilter` objects for tracking. You can replace the detection part in this example with the code to detect faces.

Alternatively, take a look at this [example that uses the KLT algorithm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-the-klt-algorithm.html) (`vision.PointTracker`) to track points. You can modify that to track multiple faces too, but that is considerably more work. You would have to do a lot of bookkeeping to keep track of which points belong to which face.

**Edit:**
Here is an [example](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47105-detect-and-track-multiple-faces) of how to use `vision.PointTracker` to track multiple faces.